# How to edit product name text in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code in composite.phtml

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
```

I need to display it as Product. Where do I change this? I changed Product name to Product in the above code but is not rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to disable and refresh your cache before the changes will show up on your website.

To do this, log in to your back end and select  'system > cache management'

Here you will be able to disable the various cache types, and refresh them. I'm pretty confident that the heading will update once you've done that.

Comment: <th><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?></th> Is the code correct? :) Or is this rendered from backend options?

I flushed the cache, disabled it. Refreshed it. Still doesn't show :(

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, it ended up that I edited the wrong file